# ASP.net - Own login module or built in?

Tags: asp.net, database, authentication, login-control

I'm creating a website in ASP.net and using a MySQL database. What would you guys suggest I do?

- Build my own login system with SQL Injection check
- Built in login control using a compliant membership provider

What are possible pro/cons of both?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use my own:

- Create an User class with a database table for it (better use an ORM like EntityFramework to do all the dirty work)
- Make a UserService class for registration, authentication, password hashing and other logic.

I've used the built-in asp.net user/roles management for one project. There is nothing wrong with it. But if you need more control over code and flexibility - consider writing your own, it will be easy.

Comment: thanks! I would prefer writing my own login too. It's hard to find a comparisson or preferences of programmers online though =/