# asp.net login module vs own login

Tags: asp.net, authentication, module

Can anyone tell me what the benefits and disadvantages are of the ASP.net login module and building your own login? Or links to where I can get more information.

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.net - Own login module or built in?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617865/asp-net-own-login-module-or-built-in)

Comment: Simplest answer: Built-in has gone through more rigorous security analysis than you will ever do, however it is less flexible than anything you can write yourself.

Comment: yes, a possible duplicate, but I need facts why the other is better, and you don't find anything on the net =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to what talljoe said it is less work and also standardised which will help anyone else that comes in need to make changes.

Unless you need some specific function that the control doesn't have, there's no real need to write your own.

Comment: This reminds me of a job once. A developer had left the company and I came in to fix a few things. I thought, "there's a lot of custom controls on this page...". The guy basically created his own controls for everything. He inherited all the standard server controls (repeater, textbox etc) and that was it. Didn't override anything or add anything. Bizarre.

Comment: nice story :P both thanks for the advise, but neither of you would be able to supply a link?

Comment: Depends on what you want the link for really.

If you want help creating new controls almost from scratch then try something like [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479311.aspx). 

If you just want to make a small tweak to the built-in Login control you can look up any tutorial about inheritng server controls like [link](http://www.vbinfozine.com/a_aspnet_derived_ctl.shtml)

Comment: well I can program both, but I prefer using my own login controls. Trouble is, when writing a thesis you need to back up your reason for choosing this and not that. Seen as though I can't find anything online, I thought maybe someone might be able to inform me.